# Why does my output of randomly selected numbers contain duplicates?

Tags: java, random, arraylist

My code needs to randomly select 6 numbers from a list ranging from `1` to `45`.

Once when I ran my code (below) the output was  `[4, 4, 17, 18, 27, 37]`. **I was not expecting any duplicates in the output. How is it possible that there are duplicates?** My code should be removing numbers from `list` as they are selected.

```
    Random rng = new Random(); 
    int size = 45;
    int sixList[] = new int[6];
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; list.size() > 39; i++){
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        if (index == 0){
            index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
            list2.add(index);
            list.remove(index);
        }else{
            list2.add(index);
            list.remove(index);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list2);
    System.out.print(list2);
```

Comment: To do a lottery pick, it's easiest to just shuffle a list of numbers from 1-45 and take the first 6.

Comment: You wanted 6 digit number ranging 1-45, and that's what you got, isn't?

Comment: I don't understand what asked here, you should clarify

Comment: but I wonder why the console prints 4, 4, 17, 18, 27, 37 even if I remove the element from the list..

Comment: Also, personally I'm not sure how your code is *meant* to prevent repetition. You're not moving items from `list` to `list2`, you're just adding random numbers between `0` and `list.size()` to `list2` . That won't prevent repetition, you need to add the removed element into the second list, not the index. I'm also not sure whether with `List<Integer>`, `list.remove()` resolves to the method that removes an element by value, or an element at a certain index. Basically your problem is that your algorithm is nowhere near correct.

Comment: @millimoose you can just do the first 6 iterations of the Knuth shuffle and you don't need to continue up to 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the index value to your list of random numbers.

Change your code

```
list2.add(index);
list.remove(index);
```

To

```
list2.add(list.remove(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

List maintain index and does not care about duplicate elements at all. To avoid duplicates you must use Set rather than List. If you have any user-defined class going in the Set, then dont forget to **implement equals() and hashcode()** which are used to determine if elements are duplicate or not by the Set classes like HashSet.

If you have primitives going in you Set, then forget about duplicates as duplicates will be automatically handled for primitive data-types like int,long etc. **So I suggest you to use Set rather than List. to avoid duplicate elements in the collection**